# LLDB Show trap opcodes in memory dump

Tags: linux, android-ndk, gdb, llvm, lldb

I'm wondering if it is possible with LLDB's memory dumper to see trap opcodes in locations where I've just set a beakpoint?
As I see LLDB is smart enough to shadow trap opcodes with original ones:

```
(lldb) memory read --format instruction --count 5 0x00000076619b5478
->  0x76619b5478: 0xf9401668   ldr    x8, [x19, #0x28]
    0x76619b547c: 0xf9400289   ldr    x9, [x20]
    0x76619b5480: 0xeb09011f   cmp    x8, x9
    0x76619b5484: 0x540000e1   b.ne   0x76619b54a0              ; <+200>
    0x76619b5488: 0xa95d7bf3   ldp    x19, x30, [sp, #0x1d0]
(lldb) breakpoint set --address 0x76619b5488
Breakpoint 3: where = libface_detector_v2_jni.so`___lldb_unnamed_symbol20247$$libface_detector_v2_jni.so + 176, address = 0x00000076619b5488
(lldb) memory read --format instruction --count 5 0x00000076619b5478
->  0x76619b5478: 0xf9401668   ldr    x8, [x19, #0x28]
    0x76619b547c: 0xf9400289   ldr    x9, [x20]
    0x76619b5480: 0xeb09011f   cmp    x8, x9
    0x76619b5484: 0x540000e1   b.ne   0x76619b54a0              ; <+200>
    0x76619b5488: 0xa95d7bf3   ldp    x19, x30, [sp, #0x1d0]
```

Here I set a break at `0x76619b5488` but dumper still shows original instruction at that place.
`help memory read` has no hints about how one could see trap opcodes.

Any ideas?

P.S. It is an LLDB bundled with Android SDK, claimed version: `7.0.0`. Target is an Android Aarch64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here I set a break at 0x76619b5488 but dumper still shows original instruction at that place.

This is very typical of debuggers: they don't want to confuse you with the breakpoint instructions they inserted, and so show you the *original* contents of memory.

On x86, doing anything else would de-sync the instruction stream (because instructions are variable length), so showing the *actual* instructions with breakpoints inserted would produce utter garbage.

> how one could see trap opcodes

You could copy (take a snapshot of) a memory region (e.g. 1 function's worth of memory) and compare it with current contents while there is a breakpoint on that function. They will not match. This is one of the ways a program can detect that it is being debugged.

You can then ask LLDB to disassemble the copied region (for the copy taken after breakpoint insertion), and you will see the breakpoint you wish to observe (but IP-relative offsets will be pointing to wrong locations).

I don't know of a simpler way to achieve that.

Comment: Wouldn't he/she be able to examine memory and see the breakpoint? Something like `x/16b 0x76619b5470`. Or would the debugger know to provide the cooked value?

Comment: @jww I don't know about LLDB, but GDB provides "cooked" value. I expect LLDB does the same -- usually this is implemented in the low-level "read memory" routine, which knows how to read actual memory from `core`, `RAM` or `remote` (depending on which backend is being used) and "cook" it to remove breakpoints. The `examine` and `disassemble` then all use this low-level `read_mem` and don't need to worry about the underlying details.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Clever trick! Surprisingly but `expression -- printf("%x\n", *((unsigned*)<patched_location_addr>))` is able to print trap bytes as well. Probably evaluation engine allows direct reads thus bypassing debugger's memory access subsystem that you've been talking about. Should it be considered a bug or not...

Comment: @Sergio I just tried GDB and LLDB. GDB produces "cooked" value, but LLDB does not. I'd say it's a bug in LLDB.

Comment: Last time I worked on it, gdb removes all breakpoints when it stops, and re-inserts them when it continues.  That may be why you aren't seeing the traps in the expression shown above.  We wanted to make lldb be fast when there are lots and lots of breakpoints, so lldb doesn't do this, it leaves the traps in place.  Since expressions access the actual memory of the process - they will then see these traps.  IMO, the benefits of not having to handle traps at every stop is well worth this little oddity.

Comment: @JimIngham Good point. That said, you can easily "cook" memory to avoid the oddity (you must already be doing the cooking when showing disassembly), while still keeping the breakpoints inserted.

Comment: The "cooking" happens when the memory is presented either by debugserver or lldb, the program's memory still has traps in it.  Since expressions are actually run in the target program (e.g. that printf runs as if the statement were part of your source code) if you haven't removed the traps, code run in the expression will see them.  That's actually useful - if you want to debug a function with weird inputs, set a breakpoint in it, and call the function using `expr -i 0 --` then debug the code.  So we really can't hide the traps from you in this way.